# How do you add conditional breaking based on another breakpoint being hit? Visual C++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, breakpoints

I have a bunch of generic code that is used a lot, which i'd like to poke into in order to deal with a bug in a certain specific case.

So I'd like to break on a set of breakpoints only if some other breakpoint has been hit. Is there a way to do this in Visual 2005? I'm using C++ code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the trigger logic is complex enough, sometimes I find it easier to just add a [DebugBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297(VS.85).aspx)(); call into the source.

Answer (score 5):

Please remember you can disable a breakpoint - it might be easier/more efficient/cleaner (then adding debug flags to your code and recompiling for example) to just disable the second breakpoint, wait till the first one breaks and then enable the second one in your breakpoints window - it takes just two mouse clicks each time you debug... :)

Answer (score 3):

Have your first breakpoint change the value of some variable to a magic value (you can use a conditional breakpoint, with an expression which changed the variable and then returned true). Then, have the second breakpoint break when the variable is at that magic value. e.g.,

```
int debug_flag = 0;
```

First breakpoint condition:

```
debug_flag = 0xdeadbeef, true
```

Second breakpoint condition:

```
debug_flag == 0xdeadbeef
```

Comment: the breakpoints are in much different areas of code. i guess i might be able to use a global variable though. i was hoping there was some way to do it without modifying the code.

Comment: Yeah, you'd probably use a global variable. If you just create a new .cpp file with just that global variable, and arrange to link it into your program, you don't have to modify any other code.

Answer (score 0):

Ten years later...

An easy way to do what the OP wants would be to use the immediate window to define a global variable, and use it as suggested by @chris-jester-young in breakpoints conditions.

Did the trick for me anyway.